# CSS looks bad in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, html

I am having a CSS problem in IE

This page looks fine in Firefox, chrome, opera....but on IE the "date bar" overlaps on the first `<li>` bar

Here : http://www.animefushigi.com/latest-episodes

CSS is as followed :

```
#content h2.other-posts {
    height: 31px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height: 31px;
    background: #2c2b2b;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #1b1b1b;
    color: #888888;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}

#content #other-posts {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#other-posts li {
    list-style: none;
    background: #151515;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-left: 1px solid #050505;
    border-right: 1px solid #151515;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #050505;
    border-top:1px solid #0f0f0f;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#other-posts li a {
    float: left;
}
```

The Wordpress PHP file is as followed :

```
<ul id="other-posts">

<?php
$postslist = get_posts('numberposts=50&order=desc&orderby=date');
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?> 
<?php the_date('', '<h2 class="other-posts">Added on ', '</h2>'); ?>

 <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
   <?php the_title(); ?>
   </a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

How can I make this all-browser friendly?

Comment: You do not have CSS problem with IE, IE have problem with CSS.

Comment: So true, but what can i do? 40% of my visitors use IE :(

Comment: My suggestion is to either implement a comprehensive reset, or use my old stand by of `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use [IE specific conditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) comments. That way you can target IE idiosyncrasies, with an IE specific stylesheet.

`<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie/specific/css.css"> <![endif]-->`

Comment: And what I put in the IE css file in this case?

Comment: Your fixes. Which will only be displayed to IE browsers.

Comment: This brings me back to the first point, what is the IE css fix for this particular problem I am having. Nobody has solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#other-posts li { display:inline }
```

instead of applying the display rule to "li a". It's the list item that you want displayed inline, not the links inside.

***EDIT : Extremely sorry. dun know where that 'without' came from.***

**Try Removing the float and specifying a width or height of the list.**

Comment: Alright so....I replace "#other-posts li a { float: left; }" WITH "#other-posts li { display:inline }" and then I delete "height: 31px;" and "height: 30px;" from the above CSS ?? Tried that and it ended up like this : http://i54.tinypic.com/2s96l47.png

Comment: Please dun remove those height values.....rather specify a specific height for 'other-posts li' & a width of 100% so that it fills its parent width.

Comment: If i remove the float, and add the display inline, it still looks same as the screenshot in my last comment. If I remove the float, and leave the rest as is, it looks fine on Firefox but on IE it's : http://i55.tinypic.com/9r0j84.jpg . (only the first date header shows)